# What does the "$*$" in "$G_1*G_2$" mean for graphs (as part of the recipe theorem for the Tutte polynomial)?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, graph-invariants

[image]

This is the recipe theorem of Tutte polynomial and I have one confusion regarding this. As mentioned in the title, What does this asterisk symbol means here in this definition. Is this the cartesian product or disjoint union?

Comment: I would guess that the symbol is defined previously in that text.

Comment: No it was not introduced anywhere above

Comment: Is it even possible that it means cartesian product? A little bit before, there is written $f(G_1 \cup G_2)$, so it seems like the domain of $f$ is stuff of the type $G$, not $G_i \times G_j$

Comment: Also, by disjoing unition do you mean $G_1 \cup G_2 - G_1 \cap G_2$>

Comment: what book is that?

Comment: Look at the inside cover at the front or the back of the book.  With many math books their will be a chart of the symbols used.

Answer (score 2):

It is a *one-point join* of $G_1$ and $G_2$.  See page 5 of [Graph Polynomials and Their Applications I: The Tutte Polynomial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.3079.pdf), by Joanna A. Ellis-Monaghan and Criel Merino.  Definition 5 on page 7 looks just like your Definition 4.1.